# ¿Cómo agregar la imagen antes de que termine el evento on click?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

soy principiante en esto de android studio y estoy intentando insertar una imagen por 1 segundo a un constraint layout al hacer on click en él y luego borrar todas las vistas que tenga ese constraint layout, adjunto el código que tengo para facilitar la lectura,

```
constraintLayoutNosotros.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ImageView img = new ImageView(activity)

            img.setId(View.generateViewId());
            img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.palito2);
            constraintLayout.addView(img);

        }
    }
    );
```

Depurando la aplicación me encuentro con el problema de que el programa finaliza el evento on click y no muestra la imagen en la aplicación,sino que después de finalizar dicho evento entra a clases internas de android studio como por ejemplo Looper.java y View.java y luego de todo eso,recien la muestra en la pantalla.

Quiero aclarar que la imagen la agrega correctamente solo que yo quiero que la agrega durante un periodo de tiempo y luego quitarla,pero al entrar a esas clases internas pierdo el control sobre eso,estuve investigando si hay algún Listener al finalizar el evento onclick o algo así y no encontré nada, ya intenté con addOnLayoutChangeListener,setOnHierarchyChangeListener y setOnTouchListener y en todas ellas siempre agrega la imagen fuera de mi alcance.Lo ultimo que se me ocurre es con alguna animación pero no estoy seguro de que sea la forma correcta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    ImageView img = new ImageView(activity);
    img.setId(View.generateViewId());
    img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.palito2);
    constraintLayout.addView(img);
    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
        // Quitar imagen acá
    }, 500);
}
```

El `500` es el tiempo en milisegundos durante el cual la imagen será visible.

Pero lo recomendado es migrar a kotlin y usar kotlin coroutines:

```
constraintLayout.setOnClickListener {
    val img = ImageView(activity).apply {
        id = View.generateViewId()
        setImageResource(R.mipmap.palito2)
    }
    constraintLayout.addView(img)
    activity.lifecycleScope.launch {
        delay(500)
        // Quitar imagen acá
    }
}
```

Debo mencionar que en casos como este sería mejor que la imagen este siempre en el layout y simplemente cambiar su visibilidad cuando lo necesites. Agregar una View para quitarla casi inmediatamente es muy costoso y no tiene mucho sentido.